# Rails routes create resource but don't generate any on the 7 default actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes defined:

```
resources :users do
  resources :suggestions do
    post :make, on: :collection
  end
end
```

I would like to tell `resources :suggestions` not to create any of the 7 default actions because I don't need them right now. With `:only` and `:except` I can limit the number of those actions being created, but I don't seem to figure how to create none of them.

Indeed, I could just leave the `resources` out and just define my `:make` route, but I would like to benefit from the automatic nesting and param handling, as well as leave a door open for a future need of several of the 7 default actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is helpful:-

```
resources :suggestions, only: [] do
end
```

Comment: I thought there was a more "railsey" syntax for this. Thank you!